# Вытащить переменные из массива

Tags: php

Как вытащить значение 'country' и 'city'

```html
array (
  'city' => 
  array (
    'id' => 703448,
    'lat' => 50.454659999999997,
    'lon' => 30.523800000000001,
    'name_ru' => 'Киев',
    'name_en' => 'Kiev',
  ),
  'region' => 
  array (
    'id' => 703447,
    'name_ru' => 'Киев',
    'name_en' => 'Kyiv',
    'iso' => 'UA-30',
  ),
  'country' => 
  array (
    'id' => 222,
    'iso' => 'UA',
    'lat' => 49,
    'lon' => 32,
    'name_ru' => 'Украина',
    'name_en' => 'Ukraine',
  ),
)
```

Comment: `$array['country']`  `$array['city']` ? Oo

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: array in geo/index.php on line 26

Comment: ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include("SxGeo.php");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$SxGeo = new SxGeo('SxGeoCity.dat');
var_export($SxGeo->getCityFull($ip));
echo $array['country'];
echo $array['city'];

Comment: Ну так ваше название массива подставьте. А вообще лучше почитать о работе с массивами в php.

Comment: омг, возьмите вы наконец какую-нибудь книгу по ПХП прочитайте. не первый вопрос задаете, которые элементарней не придумаешь.

Comment: @teran, зачем? Тут все решат и все ок :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$SxGeo = new SxGeo('SxGeoCity.dat');
$city = $SxGeo->getCityFull($ip);
var_dump($city['country']); 
var_dump($city['city']);
```

И огромный совет почитать о работе с типами данных, в частности с массивами.

Comment: Спасибо! Ошибку выводит Notice: Array to string conversion in geo/index.php on line 17

Comment: @Андрей, что вам в этом уведомлении непонятно?

Comment: @Андрей я к сожалению не знаю что у вас в 17 строке. Смотрите в свой код что у вас творится в этом месте.

Comment: 17 строка echo $city['country']; 
18 строка echo $city['city'];

Comment: хех. замените `echo` на `var_dump` если вам нужен вывод или вообще удалите эти строки. В `$city['country']` находится информация о стране. Поэтому можете работать с этой переменной.